# RegEx to match a specific format: 4 digits and 6 characters in a string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to design a RegEx in C# to match 4 digits and 6 characters in a string.

```
 string str = "Hello World! ABCD112233 fsdf sdfsdf 234324 fdsfds 4234 efwedf34ref dfsdf34f34f";
```

that matches only ABCD112233 in the above string.

```
Regex regex = new Regex("^[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{6}$", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: All the words which has first 4 alphabets followed by 6 numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use the `{n}` quantifier to match a certain number of characters like so: `[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{6}`. This will match 4 letters (A-Z, a-z) and then 6 digits (0-9).

Note: don't use `^` and `$` at the start and end as then it will only match if the whole word matches the regex.

Comment: You're right, but this one did not work -

`Regex regex = new Regex("^[A-Za-z]{4}[0-9]{6}$", RegexOptions.Multiline)`

Comment: Is it because you are using `^` and `$` (which match the start and end of a given string)?

Comment: @John is right. The `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of the string, respectively. This would only work if the whole string was like `ABCD112233`.

Comment: Omg yes, you're so right. Thank you both :)

Comment: @AbhilashV You probably want [`\b`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) at the start and end rather than `^` and `$`.